# Compile HTML partials with gulp.js

Tags: javascript, gulp

Is there a plugin available for Gulp that does the same thing as Assemble does for Grunt?

I would like to run a task for Gulp that assembles HTML partials, but I cannot find a plugin. Has anyone used one and can you provide a link to it?

---

**UPDATE: 4/21/2016**

Lately, I've been using Twig.js with Gulp, along with gulp-data to render JSON in my templates. My article goes into detail. Hint: You could also use Nunjucks, Swig.js, Handlebars etc.

**Article: [Frontend templating with Gulp and Twig.js](https://wjonthomas.medium.com/frontend-templating-with-gulp-and-twig-js-585fc0cfc689)**

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Yes, you can do it with this plugin called **[gulp-file-include](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-file-include)**

*Example :*

**# index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
  @@include('./view.html')
  @@include('./var.html', {
    "name": "haoxin",
    "age": 12345
  })
  </body>
</html>
```

**# view.html**

```
<h1>view</h1>
```

**# var.html**

```
<label>@@name</label>
<label>@@age</label>
```

Comment: Ah. Thanks. This is much less robust than Assemble, but it will work until Assemble allows their plugin to be used with Gulp.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing jthomas, but I just noticed you posted this more than a year ago, and assemble support for gulp is still non-existent so I'm not going to hold my breathe anymore... back to grunt.

Comment: Just an update, I've since been using the Swig JS templating engine with the gulp-swig plugin.

Comment: does it support nested partials, for instance in this example if view.html has another `@@include` in it???

Comment: Yep it is.. @user2727195

Comment: For anyone reading this, you can now use Assemble as a standalone library

Answer (score 12):

I made a plugin to extend html files https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-html-extend

master.html

```html
<body>
    <!-- @@placeholder=content -->
    <!-- @@placeholder=footer -->
</body>
```

content.html

```html
<!-- @@master=master.html-->

<!-- @@block=content-->
<main>
    my content
</main>
<!-- @@close-->

<!-- @@block=footer-->
<footer>
    my footer
</footer>
<!-- @@close-->
```

output

```html
<body>

<!-- start content -->
<main>
    my content
</main>
<!-- end content -->

<!-- start footer -->
<footer>
    my footer
</footer>
<!-- end footer -->

</body>
```

It may help you.

Comment: This looks great too! Defintitely going to give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: This is to extend the layout. can it also work like http://hammerformac.com/docs/tags/includes ?

Comment: @FrankFang can you please show me code example of how to add `social-share.html` into `blog.html`?

Comment: @JitendraVyas https://github.com/FrankFang/gulp-html-extend/blob/master/test/fixtures/only_include.html   Just put `<!-- @@include relative/path/to/social-share.html-->` (or `/absolute-path-starting-with-a-slash`) into blog.html.

Comment: @JitendraVyas Any problem?

Comment: @FrankFang Is it possible to have another master into master?

Comment: @JitendraVyas  It is :)  https://github.com/FrankFang/gulp-html-extend/blob/master/test/fixtures/master_b.html

Answer (score 9):

I would like to add one more:

I use [gulp-preprocess](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-preprocess).  It is great for building not only html, but also JavaScript, and can even be used in PHP.
It has simple directives:

```
    <!-- @include filename.extension -->

    <!-- @ifdef foo -->
        Included html if foo is defined
    <!-- @endif -->

    Also @ifndef (not defined)

    Variables

    <!-- @echo bar -->

   Or even cooler:

    <a href="<-- @echo linkvar -->">link</a>

  Also (as far as I can tell) unlimited sub inclusion:

   <!--  I am an included file -->
   <!-- @include relative/to/me/data.html -->
```

I have a directory tree like so:

```
     ./project root
         - build/
           - less/
             [less,..]
           - html/
               - index/
                 Index-variables.json
                 [Index-partials.html,...]
           Index.html
           [other-build-folders,..]

         - dist
           [htmlfiles,...,CSS folder,...]
```

For each rendered html file, I have a corresponding file in the build folder and a corresponding folder for that file name.  The *build file* listens for changes in the corresponding folder and preprocesses that data which then outputs to the matching file in the *dist* folder.

Since preprocess allows you to pass variables as a context object, I pass variables stored in a JSON file in the parent build folder, .e.g. `index-variables.json`, overwriting any global variables I've defined.

I use it with Livereload,so the upshot is that everytime I make a change in any html partial the page reloads almost instantly with the rendered html - we're talking less than 1 second.  In addition to being lightening fast, preprocess seems really stable-I've never had a bug.

This is an awesome way to work.

Answer (score 3):

Assemble now supports Gulp: https://github.com/assemble/assemble although at the time of posting the official Assemble website doesn't mention this, and there is very little in the way of documentation.

Comment: it would be very helpful to first explain what `Assemble` is and why would  this be worth a click

Comment: The question asks "Is there a plugin available for Gulp that does the same thing as Assemble does for Grunt?". My answer is, "Assemble now works with Gulp".  I don't see the need to explain what Assemble is as that wasn't the question.

Comment: I don't read questions, I came here from google because of the title. the title is the question ain't nobody got time for reading after it :)

Comment: Interesting that you read the answers and have time to comment, yet don't have time to read the actual question.

Comment: I never read the questions, only the answers.. if I google a question then reason suggests I want to read answers not questions, and since google brought me here because of the straight-to-the-point title, I assumed there was a strong correlation between the title and the question body, therefor saving time reading the question. works 90% of the time

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a gulp plugin called [gulp-handlebars-file-include](https://github.com/cyberxander90/gulp-handlebars-file-include)

This is a very good plugin, because it dose not create or make a custom parser like, gulp-file-include, nor define a new syntax. Instead it use [handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/), therefore, it not only parse with **handlebars**, but also you can compile your partials files with **handlebars** and even include your own **handlebars** helpers.