# Same navigation on all pages of the website

Tags: html, navigation

I want to create a vertical navigation that remains the same on all pages of my website except for the html item representing the selected page (which will be highlighted / a different color than the rest of the words). What is the best way to reuse the same div on all pages?

Comment: For reusability in your source files, plain HTML: Frames. Most use a server-side language like PHP or Python to create dynamic templates (for DRY).

Comment: If this is your first website, just cut and paste. Worry about making it more efficient later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep the vertical navigation content in a separate HTML file. And, load it in the pages by using jquery **load() function**.

For example, consider **navigation.html** that you want to display it in all pages. In all pages create an empty as

```
<div id="verticalNav"></div>
```

and load the navigation.html as shown below:

```
$("#verticalNav").load('navigation.html');
```

And, you can highlight the selected item representing the selected page by adding a css class to an item on their corresponding pages. Suppose you have an li element in your vertical navigation as:

```
<li id="contact"><a href="www.someurl.com/contact.html">contactUs</a></li>
```

on clicking it you are displaying a **contact.html** page. So, inside contact.html file you can highlight the selected item by adding class as:

```
$("li#contact").addClass("highlight");
```

And, you can specify highlight class as:

```
.highlight a{
    color: orange; 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically people use an HTML templating tool in their chosen server/client-side framework to split their HTML files up into partials and combine them in different ways.  If you don't want to have any server or client logic involved though, you can compile your own HTML partials using something like [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) (asset compiler) with an [extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21995500/compile-html-partials-with-gulp-js)

Then you would have a partial for your navigation and just include it in your pages with something like:

```
<div>
   <!-- @@navigation-->
</div>
```