# Is there a build system for HTML based on include statements

Tags: node.js, gulp, build-process

I've been using gulp for concatenation and magnification of css, javascript and html (partials) but requirement for HTML has changed.

I'm inspired from Jade because of this statement but this happens at run time (when a page is requested), I'm looking for a solution at compile/development time.

**Syntax is not important.**

```
{% include footer.html %}
```

Possibly I should be able to define something like this, and a build happens if I change/edit any partial file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
      {% include partials/header.html %}
      <div>Menu</div>
      {% include partials/menu.html %}
      {% include partials/section.html %}
      {% include partials/footer.html %}
</body>
</html>
```

I'm looking at two options but I feel I've reached a solution yet.

1. https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-mustache
2. http://handlebarsjs.com

Comment: Meteor works like this, with separate files that you "include" for sub portions of dynamic HTML.

Comment: sorry not sure how? but is there a gulp plugin that can compile the above template into html file

Comment: I am not aware of anything with gulp but I have used Meteor a little and it basically does exactly what you are describing. Small HTML files that you include once or multiple times on a page and you can update them in real time and see the changes immediately on the web page. It is a really cool framework. https://www.meteor.com

Comment: This sounds like your question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21995500/compile-html-partials-with-gulp-js

Comment: @nycynik Thanks, that's the solution... but I wonder if it supports nested compilation, for instance if the include file has an include inside in it

Comment: both of the ones you linked in your question support partials and recursion