# Modular HTML with gulp: what framework to use?

Tags: html, gulp, handlebars.js, template-engine

I have to develop some static HTML page, but I don't want to repeat myself copy/pasting common parts so, for example, I would like to include header and footer in every page.

I don't need something too much sophisticated, just and *include* feature.

Using [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) as build system I would like to have my templates in the *src/* folder and after a processing task, getting the complete html inside the *dist/* folder.

I thought to use something like [handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/partials.html), but I don't know if this is the right framework and I don't know how to integrate it in Gulp for workflow described above.

Any hint?

Comment: for header, footer, you dont need to integrate in gulp, but you can just include those in templates, almost all templating engine can do that.

Comment: I know. The Gulp part is because I want to have the complete HTML as output.

Answer (score 0):

You could absolutely use Handlebars to render static chunks of markup. But, unless you're also building some data-driven content, it might be overkill.

It sounds like you want something akin to PHP's [`include`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php).

For that, you might want to check out `.KIT` files. I recommend [`gulp-codekit`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-codekit) ([documentation here](https://incident57.com/codekit/help.html#kit)), which is based on the `.KIT` file compiler built into [CodeKit](https://incident57.com/codekit/).

Comment: No data driven stuff, only 2 simple includes. But I need complete HTML files as output. CodeKit seems to be not Open Source...any open alternatives?

Comment: CodeKit is, indeed, its own beast. But `gulp-codekit` can be used independently in your Gulp workflow. The author/team behind CodeKit offer the following in their Docs (under the heading,"*You're Locking Us Into CodeKit!*")
"The Kit compiler is [open source](https://github.com/bdkjones/Kit) and any developer is welcome to use that code to integrate Kit support into any product."

Answer (score 0):

Like in [this other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21995500/compile-html-partials-with-gulp-js), using [gulp-file-include](https://github.com/coderhaoxin/gulp-file-include) is the easiest choice for my needs.
Thanks everyone!